# Scale Bitmapfont clearly with openGL (interpolation)?

Tags: c++, opengl, bitmap-fonts

I load an bitmapfont (as png image) in my openGL Application to render characters from there at a fixed size. That's working. But: If I want to scale some glyphs at a smaller size it doesnt look great. Is there a way - without using pregenerated mipmaps (I have a big bunch of several characters and need stepless sizes) to scale this more beautiful? Some way of interpolation or something?

At the moment I use something like this (C/C++ on Mac OS X):

```
glPopMatrix();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->getID());
glScalef(0.7f, 0.7f, 0); //scale here a size

{draw vertexes & set texcoords}

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPushMatrix();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Item 17.020 in this faq: http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/fonts.htm

Comment: Thats about TrueType fonts - I'm speaking about Bitmap fonts. Its not my intention to use TrueType fonts for serveral reasons (i.e. font licensing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using Linear filtering on your textures?:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

This after binding textures.

Comment: BTW - Game Programming Gems, part 6 has an article on how to achieve good-quality scaling of signs (so also glyphs). An easy way to get much better results than with regular linear interpolation which will result in blurred borders.